# How to pass Controller Element value to View(.cshtml) div element value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I developing WEB API project using .net C#

I need to get the value from controller.cs file and use that value into View(.cshtml) file.

My Controller Code:

**HomeController.cs**

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

        XmlElement TransID = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("/CensusUploadResponse/TransactionID");
        if (TransID != null)
        {
            string ResultID = TransID.InnerText;

        }
```

I need to pass the ResultID to Index.cshtml(Ex:ResultID = 17)

MY View .cshtml file code:

**Index.cshtml**

```
   <div runat="server" id="CensusuploadDiv"  style="border:1px solid black; width:420px;">

  </div>
```

I need to assign that ResultID value to CensusuploadDiv.

I try with following method using ViewBag. but's it's not working.

Assign ResultID to ViewBag like below

```
  if (TransID != null)
        {
            string ResultID = TransID.InnerText;
            ViewBag.Test2 = ResultID;
        }
```

and i get the value in index file like below

```
<div runat="server" id="CensusuploadDiv"  style="border:1px solid black; width:420px;">
    @ViewBag.Test2
 </div>
```

But value not bind to div.

Comment: What do you mean by "bind to div"?

Comment: @DavidG I need to assign the value to div.

Comment: @DavidG Just i need to display 17 in Div

Comment: Your code should work unless the value of `XmlElement TransID = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("/CensusUploadResponse/TransactionID")` is null?

Comment: Yes, only show the value when it's not null

Comment: Yes, but is that returning null?

Comment: Then your code should work. You are either mistaken or not telling us enough information.

Comment: I need to tell if i assign  public ActionResult Index()
                            {                                                                                                   ViewBag.Test = "17";  } This value show in div. but if i use the viewBag inside the function call it's not working

Comment: Then I bet it's not reaching that line of code inside the `if` statement because the return is `null`.

Comment: @DavidG I check with break point I'm unable to show my output image to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out solution for my problem by Using TempData.

TempData help me lot...

I use TempData as follow in HomeController.cs

```
string result = strBind.ToString();
TempData["Result"] = result;
```

In view.cshtml

```
@TempData["Result"]
```

It's work fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

Do you develop Web API or ASP.NET MVC project? Best way to access values from controller in view is to use strongly typed models:

```
@model int

<div>@Model</div>
```

Example:
Index.cshtml

```
@model int

<div>@Model</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult GetId()
{
   int id;
   ....
   return View(id);
}
```

Please note, that WebApi and MVC controllers are slightly different. But this is how it works.

Comment: I'm new to webapi plz tell me where i use @model int and how i assign the value in controller.  plz show some sample code

Comment: I have expand my answer with small example. You can also see example of Web API project in default project template created in VisualStudio.

Comment: Where i need to Use "@model" int In start of the page or any other place.any difference for "@model" and "@Model"

Comment: Maybe its a little bit confusing because in this example I use int as model. But let's say I want Customer to some form. Then at the top of cshtml file I would declare used model as "model Customer" and then later in file I would use it "Model.Name" and so on. Firs you identify type of your model - "model" and then you use it with property "Model". Is that clear?